# How to see the compilation errors while coding MASM assembly in visual studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, masm

I have setup the free visual studio community 2013 for assembly programming following the instructions [here](http://kipirvine.com/asm/gettingStartedVS2013/index.htm) . Everything works fine , but I can't see the compilation errors with line numbers. In case a build is wrong here is the error output in the message box below ,which is clearly not indicating the error. So How do can I see the assemblars compilation errors in visual studio ?

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\BuildCustomizations\masm.targets(50,5): error MSB3721: The command "ml.exe /c /nologo /Zi /Fo"Debug\Moves.obj" /Fl"myFirstAssembly.lst" /I "c:\Irvine" /W3 /errorReport:prompt  /Ta"..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Irvine\Examples\ch04\32 bit\Moves.asm"" exited with code 1.
```

Comment: Well, you *could* look in the .lst file for the errors . . .

Comment: Still I have to scan the whole code , But I think MASM generates the line number and type of error at some point , where can I find that ??